# Chayei olam: "everlasting life" or "long life"?

Tags: hebrew, olam-haba-world-to-come, resurrection-of-the-dead, afterlife, daniel-book-of

I am an Italian noahide.

I see that, in the translations of the Tanakh and of the Hebrew sources in general edited by Jews , the expression "chayei olam" is constantly rendered with "eternal life" or "everlasting life" (of the two I prefer "everlasting life", since the concept of eternal presupposes, to be precise, the absence of both a beginning and an end, while the age of chayei olam undoubtedly has a beginning), as, for example, in Daniel 12: 2.

However, there are some Israeli  Orthodox Jews who contest this interpretation, arguing that the concept of "everlasting life" is not biblical, and that this translation of "chayei olam" is erroneous. According to them, the meaning of this expression is "long life ", that is, a life extended for a long and not exactly definable time, but which will have an end anyway.

I am personally perplexed, also because they support their position, in some Italian biblical forums, on linguistic observations relating to the term "olam", which according to them cannot mean "everlasting" in Hebrew, but they do not bring specific sources taken from the works of the masters of Israel, and no Orthodox rabbi I have consulted, Italian or otherwise, has ruled out that chayei olam means everlasting life.

To your knowledge, are there some Jewish sources that support the interpretation given by these people?

Comment: Do you mean to refer to life in this world or life in the world to come? (Concerning life in the world to come, Rb Hutner was very emphatic that eternal life in that context does not mean life that goes on forever, rather it means life in a timeless existence.)

Comment: When you say "_the expression 'chayei olam' is constantly rendered_", and "_for example, in Daniel 12: 2_", do you have other examples, from the Tanakh, where the expression "chayei olam" is used?

Comment: @pcoz I mean life in the world to come, that is, that phase which according to Rambam is subsequent to the second death of bodies after their resurrection

Comment: @Tamir Evan I said that badly. My reference is to Daniel 12.2, constantly translated as "eternal / everlasting life". Unless there is a mistake, the expression is also present in TB Rosh Hashanah 16b 17a, always translated in the aforementioned way

Comment: @Amos74 In which case Rav Hutner's opinion is as above.

Comment: In @Deuteronomy's [answer to "Death After Resurrection?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/135933/1368), he states that the Rishonim are divided on whether those that merit resurrection will die once again, and quotes Rambam and Ibn Ezra (from [his commentary on Daniel 12:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ibn_Ezra_on_Daniel.12.2.1?lang=bi&lang2=en)) who answer in the affirmative. It could be those Israeli Orthodox Jews, that you mention in the question, are following their position on the matter, and interpreting "chayei olam" as "long life", accordingly.